# How do I generate a wallet from a seed?

Tags: wallet, seed

Specifically, how do I generate the wallet offline with a seed. I want to use dice to generate the seed and create the address from that seed.

Comment: [Here you go. Thirty sided die.](https://www.dicegamedepot.com/30-sided-opaque-dice-d30-black/)  Just ignore 28-30 and follow aboose's answer to generate the wallet from that seed.

Answer (score 9):

Dice may not be best. IOTA Seeds are made up of A-Z and the number 9, and are 81 characters long. So you need a 27 sided dice, or need to do a LOT of dice rolls.

Once you come up with a seed, download the light wallet from github: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases

Then, input the seed you came up with there. Then, you can create addresses.

Comment: Well there are d30. Just ignore the last three as invalid and it works.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/7hos4t/secure_dice_roll_seed_generator_template/ or use this

Answer (score 4):

Download the Iota Wallet for Desktop from -> https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases

Get the "IOTA.Wallet.Setup.2.5.4.exe" (or newer)

After you install it this is what you see. In the "SEED" field enter your generated seed and click login. Yo are done.

*Careful: In order to see if you didn't make a typo on your seed note the last three characters (checksum) where the "?" is. Enter the seed again and make sure that the checksum is identical.*

[image]

**In order to generate a secure seed I would suggest the good old "Random Hat"**

Your SEED must be generated using only uppercase A to Z and the number 9

Process:

1.Take a piece of paper write the alphabet and number 9 like this: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ9

2.Cut each character with a scissor. Take a hat and put all character folded in there.

3.Mix them up and extract one piece of paper. That's the first character of your SEED.

4.Put the piece of paper back in the hat, mix again and extract the next SEED character.

5.Do this until you have an 81 character string. There you have it a random SEED that was never generated online or on a computer and can't be possibly spied upon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac, copy and paste the following code in “Terminal” and it will generate an 81 character seed with Uppercase letters and random 9’s included.

cat /dev/urandom |LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Z9' | fold -w 81 | head -n 1

Terminal does not keep a cache of your seed, however, if you are concerned, just swap a few of the generated characters around.

Copy and paste your new seed, and remember to clear your clipboard when you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

Create the seed with javascript (and/or offline):

[Seed Gist link](http://bit.ly/2izJpGC)

Create the index.html and run in the browser of your choice.

[image]

Comment: math.random() is not cryptographic secure

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS. You will get your iota stolen.

Comment: stolen?  plan javascript and I created seed offline.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of oppertunities how you can create a seed, so there are many websites *but be careful*, only use trusted websites

You can use [this link](https://iotasupport.com/gui-newseed.shtml) (it's from the IOTA support)

- For Linux you can use `cat /dev/urandom |tr -dc A-Z9|head -c${1:-81}`
- for Mac use `cat /dev/urandom |LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Z9' | fold -w 81 | head -n 1`

or you just can use [this link](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdqTgEdyKVQAVnfT5iV4ULzTbkV4hhkDkMqGBuot8egfA) to generate your seed.
it's generated in your browser and not sent anywhere.

Moreover you can copy your seed in an editor and change some parts of your seed (e.g replace some `A` with a `J`)

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, you might create you seed offline with this:
https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/c3534839-17ed-49e8-99bc-22f1dad7e33e

Comment: Providing a random link without any explanation why one should click it is not providing a high quality answer.

Comment: not answering the question at all